# Arrows in Chemfig User-Package - Resolve Too Large Arrows

Tags: chemfig

I am trying to use the chemfig user-package. This is the code I am using:

```
\begin{figure}[htb!]
\centering
\chemfig{R-CH=CH_2 -> C(-[3]H)(-[5]H)=C(-[1]H)(-[7]R) -> -C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]R)-}
\caption{Vinylgruppe mit allgemeinem Rest R}
\label{Vinylgruppe}
\end{figure}
```

I am using the figure environment in order to point to the figure with \autoref{Vinylgruppe}

This gives me the following result:

[image: Resolve Too Large Arrows]

I would like to get smaller, more elegant reaction arrows. Does someone know how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please give a fully compilable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `chemfig` arrows are supposed to be drawn with the `\arrow` command. Each molecule is represented in a separate `\chemfig` command and the arrows are placed in between. You also need `\schemestart` and `\schemestop` commands around the reaction.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb!]
\centering
\schemestart
\chemfig{R-CH=CH_2} \arrow \chemfig{C(-[3]H)(-[5]H)=C(-[1]H)(-[7]R)} \arrow \chemfig{-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]R)-}
\schemestop
\caption{Vinylgruppe mit allgemeinem Rest R}
\label{Vinylgruppe}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

For more information and examples see the `chemfig` [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf), specifically the section on reaction schemes starting from page 49.